# C : Trying to split an integer into an array returns array of length 2, no matter the size of the integer

Tags: c

So I want to split each digit of a decimal number into an array. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int * splitNumberIntoArr(int num) {

    int i = num;
    int modulus,newNum;
    static int arr[5];
    int j = 0;

    while (i > 0) {
        modulus = i % 10;
        newNum = i / 10;
        arr[j] = modulus;
        j++;
        i = newNum;
    };

    return arr;
};

int main() {
    int num;
    printf("Provide a number:\t");
    scanf("%d", &num);   

    int *arr;
    arr = splitNumberIntoArr(num);

    int k;
    for(k = 0; k <= sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); k++) {
        printf("%d\n",arr[k]);
    
    return 0;
};
```

When num is an integer consising of 3 digits, the code works how it is supposed to.

[image: Example - 3 Digits]

However, when the input consists of more than 3 digits, the array that is returned by the  `splitNumberIntoArr()`

function only returns an array of length 2.

for example,

[image: Example - 5 Digits]

Since I am new to C, I struggle to understand why this problem even exists, taking into consideration the fact that the declared array is of length 5: `static int arr[5];`

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Declare `arr` in `main()` and pass it to `splitNumberIntoArr`. Then `main()` knows how bit `arr` is using `sizeof(arr)`.

Comment: In `main`, in your `for` loop you did (e.g.) `for (k = 0; k <= X; k++)` where `X` was `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` [which was incorrect]. You want: `for (k = 0; k < X; k++)`

Comment: Note that `static int arr[5];` only allows for 5 digits (i.e. `num` can have a max value of 99999). A 32 bit `int` can have up to 10 digits, but why be stingy [with memory]? How about: `static int arr[20];` That should work even for a 64 bit number.

Comment: Welcome to C. Forget everything you know or assume about arrays. Learn C arrays from scratch.

Comment: Do you _want_ the split number to come out _reversed_ (e.g. `123` --> `3 2 1`)?

Comment: It is easier to just take the input as a string.

Comment: _function only returns an array of length 2_: No. Function doesn't return an array. In C, a function cannot return an array. It returns a pointer to the first element of an array. The calling function doesn't know the array size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for memset

void splitNumberIntoArr(int num, int *arr) {

    int i = num;
    int modulus, newNum;
    int j = 0;

    while (i > 0) {
        modulus = i % 10;
        newNum = i / 10;
        arr[j] = modulus;
        j++;
        i = newNum;
    };
}

int main() {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int arr[32];
    memset(arr, -1, sizeof(arr));
    splitNumberIntoArr(num, arr);

    for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) && arr[k] != -1; k++) {
        printf("%d\n",arr[k]);
    }
}
```

In `main()`, the `sizeof(arr)` is known, because it lies on the stack.

Comment: `for` loop should be `<` and not `<=`

Comment: The output is backwards, of course...

Comment: Caching `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` would be a good idea, otherwise it is calculated on every iteration. But I just left the original version.

Comment: No, using `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` is fine. It's a constant [almost by definition].